# Exportar datos de una datagridview a un excel personalizado

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

tengo problemas al tratar de exportar datos de mi datagridview a una plantilla excel.xlt, los datos los estoy jalando de un procedimiento almacenado de mi SQL. Cuando genero el reporte en el datagridview salen normal los datos pero al momento que pongo en mi boton EXCEL para exportarlo no logro conseguir que pasen los datos a mi excel predefinido que tengo modificado, solo quiero que pasen los datos a las celdas que quiero.

```
CREATE PROC SP_REPORTES
@TEXTOBUSCAR VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT  COD_PROV AS 'Código',
        SIA_PROV AS 'SIAF',
        NOM_PROV AS 'Proveedor',
        P.COD_UE AS 'CÓDIGO UE',
        FEC_INI AS 'FECHA INICIO',
        FEC_FIN AS 'FECHA FIN',
        OBS_PROV AS 'OBSERVACIÓN'
FROM TB_PROVEEDOR P
INNER JOIN TB_UE
ON P.COD_UE = TB_UE.COD_UE
INNER JOIN TB_OFICINA
ON P.COD_OFICINA = TB_OFICINA.COD_OFICINA
INNER JOIN TB_TAREAS
ON P.COD_TAREAS = TB_TAREAS.COD_TAREAS
INNER JOIN TB_UNIDADMEDIDA
ON P.COD_UM = TB_UNIDADMEDIDA.COD_UM
INNER JOIN TB_FF
ON P.COD_FF = TB_FF.COD_FF
INNER JOIN TB_CLASIFICADOR
ON P.COD_CLASIFICADOR = TB_CLASIFICADOR.COD_CLASIFICADOR
WHERE SID_PROV LIKE @TEXTOBUSCAR + '%' OR NOM_PROV LIKE @TEXTOBUSCAR + '%' OR 
REC_PROV LIKE @TEXTOBUSCAR + '%'
ORDER BY FEC_PROV ASC
END
GO
```

Esta es mi script de mi C#, estoy tratando de hacerlo pero no logro encontrar información

```
public static void ExportarExcel()
    {
        string cRuta = "";
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oApp = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oBook = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks oBooks = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oHoja = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oCeldas = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRango = null;

        try
        {
        if (otbCabecera.Rows.Count >= 1)
            {
                oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                oApp.Visible = false;
                oBooks = oApp.Workbooks;
                cRuta = Application.StartupPath + "\\Plantillas\\Reporte.xlt";
                oBook = oBooks.Open(cRuta, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
                oHoja = (Excel.Worksheet)oBook.ActiveSheet;
                oCeldas = oHoja.Cells;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!(oCeldas == null))
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oCeldas);
                oCeldas = null;
            }
            if (!(oHoja == null))
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oHoja);
                oHoja = null;
            }
            if (!(oBook == null))
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oBook);
                oBook = null;
            }
            if (!(oBooks == null))
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oBooks);
                oBooks = null;

            }
            if (!(oApp == null))
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oApp);
                oApp = null;
            }
        }
```

---

@Luis Carlos Donado, encontré un código similar al tuyo, lo malo que me guarda todos los campos y quiero algunas columnas no guardar, ya que son códigos y no creo que le interese eso al cliente.

```
private void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView grd)
    {
        SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
        fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
        if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
            aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
            hoja_trabajo =
                (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabajo
            for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
            libros_trabajo.Close(true);
            aplicacion.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: No he trabajado con archivos xlt, tengo un metodo para archivos xlsx, no se si te sirva o lo puedas adaptar, el metodo toma una tabla y escribe celda a celda como si fuera una matriz.

Comment: Sería genial ver el código para analizarlo y espero que me logre salir

Comment: Lo publique como respuesta, espero te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Ejemplo que toma los datos de un datatable (dt) y los copia a una hoja excel existente, el archivo se guarda con otro nombre y ruta

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
object misvalue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
try
{
    //copiar el contenido de un datatable en un archivo existente de Microsoft Excel
    oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    oXL.Visible = false;
    oXL.ScreenUpdating = false;
    oXL.UserControl = false;

string directorio = "Carpeta de Ubicacion de la plantilla");
oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open(directorio + "Plantilla_Radicacion.xlsx"));
oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

//Copiar datos de la tabla recorriendola como matriz y asigando fila a fila y campo a campo en Excel , la tabla es zero-index y excel el indice empieza en 1
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        oSheet.Cells[(i + 1), (j + 1)] = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
    }
}


string nomarchivo = "Ruta completa y nombre del archivo que se va a guardar";


oWB.SaveAs(nomarchivo, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

oWB.Close();
oXL.Quit();
```

Comment: Te respondí en otro comentario, como podría hacer para guardar algunas columnas que yo quiero y otras no.

Comment: Te tocaria usar un if al momento del segundo bucle bien sea por el numero del indice o por el nombre de la columna, o tambien podrias tomar el datattable y sacar una vista de las columnas necesarias, o la consuylta que te trae la data no incluir esas columnas, hay diversas formas de hacerlo.

Comment: Me podrías dar una mano con eso por favor, te lo agradecería mucho.