# Generar Excel mediante DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, excel, datagridview

Mi codigo de exportacion hacia excel me funciona correctamente, sin embargo al yo contar con cinco campos (`Id`, `nombre`, `categoria`, `piezas` y `puntos`) solo necesito las ultimas 4. `id` no me sirve en el archivo de excel y me gustaria que no apareciera como puedo quitarlo?

Aqui se muestra el codigo:

```
 //Metodo de excel
    private void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView grd)
    {
        SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
        fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
        if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
            aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
            hoja_trabajo =
                (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabajo
            for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value?.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
            libros_trabajo.Close(true);
            //Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;//cambia el tipo de cursor al tipo wait
            aplicacion.Quit();
           // Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;//restaura el tipo de cursor de defecto
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Exportar datos de una datagridview a un excel personalizado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/315462/exportar-datos-de-una-datagridview-a-un-excel-personalizado)

Comment: Casi, ahora entiendo que debo hacer una condicional en el segundo bucle, pero nose me ocurre que puedo escribir para esa condicion

Comment: y si remueves el id desde que cargas el datagrid?

Comment: @jorgetl2505 Te coloque una respuesta que tiene dos variantes de como plantear esa condicional, te recomiendo que la revises, las pruebes y verifiques cual de ellas es más conveniente según tus preferencias y las características de tu problema, además deben existir otras variantes de como plantear esa condicional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente debes evitar que en tu lazo por las celdas de cada fila, se agregue la celda de la columna `Id`, si cambias el lazo for por un lazo foreach se puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
//Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabaj
for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
  int j = 0;
  foreach (DataGridViewCell celda in grd.Rows[i].Cells)
  {
     if (grd.Columns[celda.ColumnIndex].Name != "Id")
     {
        if(celda.Value != DBNull.Value)
        {
           hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = celda.Value?.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
           hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = null;
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

Otra variante seria, si sabes que la columna Id tiene `Index = 0`, iniciar tu lazo `for` en 1, evitando que se agregue esa fila

```
//Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabajo
for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
     {
        if (grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != DBNull.Value)
        {
           hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value?.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j] = null;
        }
     }
}
```

Yo particularmente prefiero la primera, pues es independiente del valor del `Index`  de la columna `Id`

Comment: @jorgetl2505 Gracias por elegir como la mas acertada la respuesta. Gracias además por la puntuación.